# Excel input dates show incorrectly

Tags: excel

I want the cells to display dates in the format `dd.mm.yyyy` which is done correctly, but it only takes input in the form of `mm/dd/yyyy`. How do I change it so the input it takes is either `dd.mm.yyyy` or `dd/mm/yyyy`? I tried doing the Text to columns selecting `MDY` but it didnt help, it only changed the display if dates were already displayed in `MDY` format.

My language settings are English UK and my locale is set to Danish.
Display cell: [image]

Input:

[image]

I want the input to interpret `dd.mm.yyyy` or at least `dd/mm/yyyy`. I am not talking about switching the format cells to date. That is what I have already done in the display. I want the input to not have to be in M/D/Y format in order for Excel to understand it is a date I am giving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my own question.

To change the input display, you go into your system settings and change the regional time/date settings. Mine was by default set to US. Changing it to UK worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Select the cell with a date in Excel, press Ctrl+1 to open the Format Cells window and switch to the General tab. There you can choose the type as date, and then it offers you a range of formats. You can even use a custom format if you like

Comment: That doesn't work. It still doesn't understand if I input the displayed format.